# Why do merge conflicts happen?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

For example:

- I have a master branch.
- I create a file `file.txt` and I write `Master branch` in it, and then I commit it.
- I create another branch called `fix20`, and modify the text of `file.txt` to `This is fix20 branch`. Then I commit it.
- I switch to the master branch and then I create a branch `hotfix` and switch to it.
- I modify `file.txt` to have the text `This is the HotFix`. After that I commit the changes.
- Now I switch back to the master branch and merge it with the hotfix. The file (with no problems) changes it text to `This is the HotFix` (They are basically merged)).

Now I merge with the fix20 branch and I get a merging conflict. The `file.txt` has both the text from fix20 branch and the text, that I had after merging with HotFix. At this point, I should open an editor and decide, what should be left, and what should be removed.

The question is: Why does the merging conflict happen the second time? Why didnt I decide which text to leave, when I merged the master with the hotfix? Why havent the files been merged, when I merged with fix20 branch (why the text was not just replaced as with the hotfix)? Why basically this conflict happens the second time and not the first one???

Comment: branch fix20 has a diferent commit history than the master branch, which master does not have, git (or any other version tool) cannot know if you want to keep both texts or just one of them

Comment: @NikosM. Then why is the question on what do I want to keep, does not appear when I merge it with the hotfix??

Comment: because master changed a certain commit but fix20 has another one as well, so the tool cannot know

Comment: @NikosM. Is it like the situation, when there is a need for rebasing?

Comment: not necessarily, except if you want to rebase the branch, eg you may need to just add to the branch, but not rebase

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that you know your intention... but Git doesn't.

This is how Git looks at what you did: you made two independent changes to the same line. When you merge the first one, your intention is clear: you want the change to become part of master. Since there haven't been any changes in master itself since you branched off, there is no problem with that: Git can always directly merge a piece of code *if only one side of the merge changed it*.

When you try to merge your second change, that is no longer true: by merging the first branch, you have introduced changes to master that are not directly "compatible" with the changes in the second branch. Git calls this: "the branches have diverged". Git doesn't know whether you'd rather keep the stuff you merged from the first branch, or the stuff you are merging from the second branch.

In your situation it's obvious *to you* because the second branch is a newer fix of the same thing... but many merges involve more complicated changes to the code, and maybe the correct way to merge the second branch is to *combine* the changes from the two merges: often, if two merged changes touch the same line of code, both will have to leave their marks on it.

Example original code:

```
send_request("bake cookies")
```

Branch 1:

```
send_request("bake cookies", additions: ["chocolate"])
```

Branch 2:

```
send_request("bake cookies", flour: "wheat")
```

The correct way to merge both of these probably isn't to take one of the two lines verbatim, it's probably more like this:

```
send_request("bake cookies", flour: "wheat", additions: ["chocolate"])
```

Since you know the intention of your code much better than Git, Git will never make an automatic decision in this kind of situation.

Comment: i would add that git like any version tool works with (sequences of) diffs, **diffs describe what changed to what**. In the case of master the diff is clear, the one line changed to another, but in the case of branch, the diff cannot apply as is (**note**, the same happens with all version tools since they use diff patterns, not only with git). Each version history in a tool is just a series of diffs (applied in sequence), git differs from other tools in other respects but not this

Answer (score 3):

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416225/why-is-it-resulting-in-a-merge-conflict/34416917#34416917) for full details. Its the same problem that you have but in a slightly different scenario

---

#### In short:

The answer is that there is a **conflict** because there isn't any [`merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) commit for the 2 branches.

---

#### Here are the steps you described

[image]

---

Im using 3-diff ads the diff algorithm

Here is the content of the file:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
This is hotfix branch
||||||| merged common ancestors
Master branch
=======
This is fix20 branch
>>>>>>> fix20
```

---

I have tried to generate some graphical presentation of your problem but it takes too much time.

Ill try to answer here as clear as i can be.

Since you have several branches whenever you do a merge git try to find out where was the split done (on which commit you have derived and opened the new branch). Then from this point it generates the diff and trying to merge the files.

I our case we have this:

```
master            master  master
   \----- hotfix --- /     |
   |                       |
   \----- fix20  ----------/


// To view the patch that will be created for the merge you can run
// this command and you will see the commits that will be merged.
git log ^master fix20
```

In your case you will see that its trying to merge a commit which updated the same file (both branches were created from the same commit [merge-base commit]) and it results in conflict.

Comment: What do you mean by `merge-base`? P.S. I  see, that this post is like mine, but I still cant understand, why that occurs

Comment: Writing why, will take me few monutes

Comment: Can you, please, at least explain what did you mean by merge-base? The question is basically: "why does this happen", and you just wrote about it happening.

Comment: Wait, still writing full answer for you. few more monutes

Comment: Using the common definition of merge base, there is definitely one here, namely the commit `c4d6cfb` (root commit).